# How to get notification of workflow errors?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am having issues were a workflow is stalled because there is an issue with sending an email (send email activity). Typically, this is simply solved by resuming the workflow. I'm wondering if there any way to react to a workflow error, so the user knows they need to go in and resume the workflow.

I'm also wondering about this relative to a workflow that is attempting to assign a task to a user who no longer exists in the CRM or one that has an invalid email address, which I'm assuming would cause errors in workflows as well.

Any other suggestions related to this sort if issue would be welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My point of view, is that monitoring can't be done inside CRM, because all CRM processes could be problematic (what happen if a workflow fails to monitor another workflow?)

The way I already done that, was by adding a SQL query (that check the workflow instance state) to a monitoring tool (such as Nagios with the [check_mssql_health](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Databases/Plugins/SQLServer/check_mssql_health/details)) or you can just create a small service that will send emails using SMTP.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was a built in way to handle normal sorts of issues (missing data, bad email address etc.). I'll look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I can't think of an automated way to do it (you could try attaching a workflow to a workflow instance record, but I'm not sure if that will do it).

I'd probably try to build a utility to query workflow instance records, and then notify users if necessary based on their status.