# Dynamics CRM 2013 : Get a notification when workflow fail

Tags: dynamics-crm

I search a method to get a notification when workflow fail. The perfect scenario, it is "When a Workflow finish on error (or other defined states), the administrator receives an email."

It is trivial, but the best response I found is :
[How to get notification of workflow errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852908/how-to-get-notification-of-workflow-errors)

The solution would be to develope a program to make periodic check. It's a good idea a product, maybe as a solution. But it will be too long.

Then I am looking for a intermediate solution for my real pressing need :
"Notification on custom workflow activity's error"

Maybe the precedent idea exist already, it will be perfect. Else a suggestion for intermediate solution would help me.

For example, output parameter to check the result. Not sure it's possible, my knowledge on CRM is limited.

(Solution have to be compatible with Dynamics CRM Online, SQL isn't permitted)

Comment: Any reason you can't create a dashboard to show the problem entries?

Comment: Thank, but it isn't a notification.

Comment: When WF fails is when WF throws an unhandle exception or when it doesn't match your bussiness logic.

Comment: WF fails when WF throws an unhandle exception. But I can catch this exception and use output parameter boolean WF.Success for the condition to send a email. But the workflow isn't the fail state in the task system.